# Updating an entity record in CRM using Entity Framework

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2015

I been trying lately to update records in CRM 2015 Entity using the auto generated code from the SDK tool of CRM CrmSvcUtil.exe
using the code

```
CrmConnection con = new CrmConnection("CRM");
XrmServiceContext ctx = new XrmServiceContext(con);
var nn = ctx.TestEntity.Where(x => x.Name== "12132").FirstOrDefault();
nn.Name="test";
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

but all the changes done are ignored after save Changes, I noticed that the entity state of the changed record still unchanged.

When using the `ctx.UpdateObject(nn);` and `ctx.Update(mm);` the application throws the following errors:

> The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services:request. The InnerException message was 'Error in line 1 position 13371. Element 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic:value' contains data from a type that maps to the name 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/7.1/Contracts:ConcurrencyBehavior'. The deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this name. Consider changing the implementation of the ResolveName method on your DataContractResolver to return a non-null value for name 'ConcurrencyBehavior' and namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/7.1/Contracts'.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.

or this

> EntityState must be set to null, Created (for Create message) or Changed (for Update message)

and when trying to set the entity state manually to changed I get this error

> The entity is read-only and the 'EntityState' property cannot be modified. Use the context to update the entity instead.

Knowing that I can create new records using the same auto generated code by using `ctx.AddObject()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `ctx.UpdateObject` before calling `ctx.SaveChanges()`.

`UpdateRequest.ConcurrencyBehavior` was introduced in CRM 2015 Update 1. It appears to me that you have a mismatch between the version of CRM and the version of CrmSvcUtil you are using. You must be using a newer version of the SDK Tools.

Since you are using the RTM version of CRM you can download and use the corresponding RTM version of the [CRM 2015 SDK core tools (version 7.0.1)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreTools/7.0.1). After re-generating your context with CrmSvcUtil from that version you should no longer see any errors related to `UpdateRequest.ConcurrencyBehavior`.

Comment: I am using on premises Microsoft Dynamics® CRM 2015
(7.0.0.3543) (DB 7.0.0.3543) and if i use update or updateObject an exception will be fired as shown in the question

Comment: OK. In that case you can get the RTM version of the SDK tools. I have updated the answer accordingly.